# Can't seem to get my PHP form to send as though from user's email

Tags: php

I have tried everything but I can't seem to add the function to make it so that the email appears in my inbox as though from the user's email rather than my host name.

I've tried adding the header attributes but it still didn't seem to work.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "julia@hotmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */

$email = check_input($_POST['email']);


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "
The email below would like to be added to the mailing list.

E-mail: $email

";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: trial2.html');
exit();


/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have even tried to set the `from` header, though you mention you have.  Can you show your code with attempt to set from header?

Comment: Start by removing the `@` in `@mail($email_to`

Comment: Did you know you are sending your mail twice (`@mail` sending the first time)?  Although, most of the variables are not set in the first instance.  In the second instance, you don't list the headers.

Comment: I didn't know that. Look I am no a programmer at all, everything I learn is from google and these forums. So any help will be appreciated. If you could point out the error ill remove it.

Comment: Thanks Fred but that didn't help

Comment: @baybeejulia You have 2 things wrong and they're both what we call in the programming world, **undefined variables**. Being `$email_subject` and `$subject`. For testing purposes, put `$email_subject = "Email subject test";` then under that put `$subject = "Subject test";` Put both underneath `$myemail = "julia@hotmail.com";` and give it a try. That *should* make your form work.

Comment: @baybeejulia **Variables** usually start with an `$` sign, *usually but not always.*

Comment: @baybeejulia I also noticed another undefined variable, `$email_to`. Another reason why your form is failing. Try setting it, for testing purposes to the same email as you have for yours.

Comment: That didn't work Fred. Thanks anyway, I found another form that will do the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also while developing and debugging, remove or comment out the `header("Location:` redirect to see PHP's error output

Comment: @baybeejulia You're welcome. Forms can be tricky at times, just need to find a working example and then build from there. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `$headers` from here:

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

and put it in here:

```
/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
```

Then remove the first line (copied from a site somewhere I'd guess)

You should be left with

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Note:** your regex validating the email address will fail on addresses like `myname@example.co.uk` or `myname@email.example.com`. use PHP's `filter_var` instead.

**2nd note:** even if you get this to work your ISP may well block any mail that doesn't appear to originate from an email account on their servers, so the mail won't be delivered anyway. Better to set up a dummy account like `webform@mydomain.com` (use your actual domain), use that as a from address and include the user email in the body of the message.

Comment: You're better off doing a re-write, then explaining it afterwards .

Comment: Thanks for the help Mike, I got it to work with another piece of code.

Comment: @Fred Sorry - I don't follow.